# how to checked the checkbox after fetching the data from database using jquery and php

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

when user click on a button it displays the dynamic data fetched from the database along with the appropriate check box ..so user has select or check the checkbox of some data and submit the result then those data are stored in database.
again that user clicked the same button then again those data are displayed but this time the data which are selected buy the user previously should be checked. I am trying to do that but enable to write code for it in jquery.

below is my code...

**javascript**

```
 $(document).ready( function() {    
        $('#location_choose').click(function(e){
                branch();
                document.getElementById('brn_light').style.display='block';

                document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block';

        });

        function branch()
        {               
            //alert(user_id);
            $.ajax({
                        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>/login/branch",
                        data: {},
                        type: "post",
                        cache: false,
                        success: function (data)
                        {
                            //alert(data);
                            var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
                            var result = "";
                            <?php foreach($resultsb as $rows){?>


                            for ( var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++ ) 
                            {

                                result+="<table id='branchtable'><tr height='25px' ><td>&nbsp&nbsp</td><td ><input class='test' type='checkbox' name='branch_name' value="+obj[i].id+"<?php echo ($rows['branch_id']=="+obj[i].id+"? 'checked' : '');?>></td><td width='15px'></td><td width='630px'><b>"+obj[i].branch_name+
                                    "</b></td></tr><tr><table id='branch_address' style='background-color:#EBF5FB'><tr><td>&nbsp&nbsp</td></tr><tr><td width='60px'></td><td width='440px'>"+obj[i].address+"</td><td width='40px'></td></tr><td>&nbsp</td></table></tr><tr></tr></table>";

                            }
                            <?php }?>
                            //alert(result);

                            document.getElementById("branch_table").innerHTML=result;
                        },
                        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) 
                        {
                            //alert(thrownError);
                        }
                });
        }

    });
```

i tried using

```
    <?php echo ($rows['branch_id']=="+obj[i].id+"? 'checked' : '');?>
```

in above code but still it doesnt checked the previous selected one.

Comment: do you have some code to show us?

Comment: You can't compare a php variable with a javascript variable like that. PHP get's parsed on the server. De result will then be sent to the browser that runs the js.

Comment: then how can i compare it? because data are printing dynamically..even instead of javascript value i directly wrote some number id still its not working

Comment: what does $resultsb array contains

Comment: You need to rethink this completely. Why don't you generate everything with PHP on the page your calling with ajax and just return the result?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Comment: it contains the id's of the selected data. @ChaitanyaGhule

Comment: your php is not close where your if condition is start in table

Comment: it is closed after the for loop of the obj @MayankVadiya

Comment: <?php echo ($rows['branch_id']=="+obj[i].id+"? 'checked' : '');?> here you can use javascript instead of php.

Comment: It's easy to check a checkbox on data generated dynamically via ajax code.. but you have mixed php unnecessarily just to comapre obj[i].id in success function and never used anywhere while generating table element using js.

Comment: how ? @MayankVadiya

Comment: By using ajax it displayed all the object but i have to checked only the slected one then how can i do it using ajax....by calling another function in usse ajax in that? @ChaitanyaGhule

Comment: (<?php echo ($rows['branch_id'] ?> == "++obj[i].id++") ? "checked" : " "

Comment: what does your checkbox actually refers to w.r.t. branch_name

Comment: Severity: Parsing Error

Message: syntax error, unexpected '?>' this error has encountered @MayankVadiya

Comment: it refers to the id of that branch_name @ChaitanyaGhule

Comment: have tried with close with `;` after `]`

Comment: yup now its showing unexpected ; @MayankVadiya

Comment: `echo $rows['branch_id']` try like this @ArchanaGupta

Answer (score 0):

Give The Same Class of Checkbox and Write Jquery Code

```
<html>
<head>

<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {

                $( '.select_all_text').click(function() {

                         var is_check = $(".select_type").prop('checked');
                                        if(is_check == false)
                                        {
                                            $(".select_type").prop('checked', true);
                                            $(''.select_all_text").text('De-select All');
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            $(".select_type").prop('checked', false);
                                            $('.select_all_text").text('Select All');
                                        }


                    });


});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<p style="position: sticky; z-index: 100; width: 50%;"><a  id="select_all" onclick="check_uncheck" style="margin-right: 2%;" href="javascript:void(0)">Select all</a> 
 <?php
        foreach($data_list as $data)
              {
              ?>
              <input type="checkbox" name="select_type[]" value="<?php echo $item_id; ?>" class="select_type" id="select_type"/>

            <?php
              }
 ?>
</body>
</html>
```